# GenericType in React.FC<Props<T>>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm building a React App based on Hooks, also exploiting TypeScript.
I've wrote a component that renders a list, and among its `props`, it expects `props.items`, which type is a generic `T`:

```
export interface ISelectableListProps<T extends { isDisableInList?: boolean }> {
    /** Specifies the item of the list. */
    items: T[];
    /** Unique REACT key used to re-initialize the component. */
    key?: React.ReactText;
    /** Specifies the template of each item. */
    itemTemplate: (item: T) => JSX.Element;
}
```

Notice that, in the interface, `T` also extends `{ isDisableInList?: boolean }`, and that's because each item may have that property, used to disable the item in the list.

Now, for what concern the SelectableList component, I'd like to write this:

```
const SelectableListComponent: React.FC<ISelectableListProps<T>> = <T extends {}>(props) => { ... }
```

But TypeScript gives me one error, and one problem:

1. **ERROR:** Type `T`, in `ISelectableListProps<T>` is not found;
2. **PROBLEM:** Type of `props` is not inferred anymore: it has `any`. Instead, by removing the `<T extends {}>`, `props` type is inferred to be `React.PropsWithChildren<ISelectableListProps<any>>`;

The only workaround I've found is to define a `ItemType`, like this:

```
type ItemType = { isDisableInList?: boolean } & { [key: string]: any };
```

And then write the component like this:

```
const SelectableListComponent: React.FC<ISelectableListProps<ItemType>> = props => { ... }
```

But doing so, when using the component, `props.items` is expected to be a `ItemType[]`, and not a Generic type. In fact, I would like to call the component like this:

```
<SelectableList<MyType> items={...} itemTemplate={...} />
```

But, as I said, the items is expected to be an `ItemType`:
[image]

By the way, no error is given, because `ItemType` has `& { [key: string]: any }`, but it seems to me "hacky", almost like using `any`.

Is there any way I can accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to use `React.FC` to define a generic component. You can just use a simple function definition or an arrow function, but letting TS infer the type:

```
export interface ISelectableListProps<T extends { isDisableInList?: boolean }> {
    /** Specifies the item of the list. */
    items: T[];
    /** Unique REACT key used to re-initialize the component. */
    key?: React.ReactText;
    /** Specifies the template of each item. */
    itemTemplate: (item: T) => JSX.Element;
}

const SelectableListComponent = <T extends {}>(props: ISelectableListProps<T>) => <></>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#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-Bm3nhb18-sDwdDivE2UjhxjmPjiYAjOnM9mUXmS-ivEWSzkYBBejRo0x1nxq7X615-E2WzoGJ0QMIWN2KG4gA)

Comment: It's a really good workaround, but my ESLint complains that I didn't give a return type. Thus, I have to add `: React.Element | null =>`.
Maybe you have a better workaround now that time has passed?